# Prove $\{x_n\}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\{x_n\}$, a sequence such that:
>   $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \left| {x_{n+2}-x_n} \right| < {1 \over 2^n}; \quad  
> \lim_{n \to \infty } ({x_{n + 1}} - {x_n}) = 0$

I translated the above to:
$$\begin{array}{l}
 {x_n} - \frac{1}{{{2^n}}} < {x_{n + 2}} < {x_n} + \frac{1}{{{2^n}}} \\ 
 {x_n} - \varepsilon  < {x_{n + 1}} < {x_n} + \varepsilon  \\ 
 \end{array}$$

But at this point I'm kinda stuck. I guess I need to "glue" the two statements somehow. I also considered, treating $X_{odd}$ and $X_{even}$. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Btw. your series is  sequence.

Comment: Of course, I'll correct that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y_n=x_{2n}$ and $z_n=x_{2n+1}$. Show that $\{y_n\}$ and $\{z_n\}$ converge. If $y,z$ are their limits, show that $y=z$.

Comment: I actually thought about doing that. It seems to me that in order to prove that, you don't need the statement:  
$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } ({x_{n + 1}} - {x_n}) = 0$. Because obviously $1 \over {2^n}$ limit goes to zero, then why do we need the statement about the limit?

Comment: Yes, but what about $u_{2n}=1$,  $u_{2n+1}=0$? It satisfies the first assumption, not the second... and does not converge. Note that the first hypothesis does not refer to the difference between two *consecutive* terms.

Comment: Oh snap. Of course :)

Comment: hmm..Can you demonstrate how to show $\{y_n\}$ converges. I'm having troubles with writing it rigorously.

Comment: It pretty much boils down to saying this is a Cauchy sequence, and that the reals form a complete metric space.